# Creating a repeating numerical pattern using a formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm trying to create a repeating numerical pattern using a formula.

Example of the numerical pattern `-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` then it repeats

`-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`

My thoughts where to use / alter the formula from [https://oeis.org/](https://oeis.org/A023482) **(-12 + 13*x)/(1 - x)^2** then add a **Mod** to limit the range between -12 and 12 somehow.

[image: img1a]

I tried the formula from [https://oeis.org/](https://oeis.org/A023482) **(-12 + 13*x)/(1 - x)^2** but when I create the formula in Libreoffice Calc (like excel).  I get something very different.

[image: img 1]

Any ideas how to create this repeating sequence `-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,-12,-11,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` using a formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) on OEIS, not just a function.   To find the $n$th term of the sequence it corresponds to, you need to find its $n$th derivative at $x=0$ and divide by $n!$. So if $G(x)=(-40 + 41x)/(1 - x)^2$ and you wanted $a_3$ then you would say $G'''(x)=  \frac{-222+246x}{(1-x)^5}$ and so $a_n=\frac{G'''(0)}{3!}=\frac{-222}{6}=-37$

Turning to your repeating sequence, you have $a_n=a_{n-25}$ so your generating function could have $1-x^{25}$ in the denominator to get the repeating pattern

You then have to choose a suitable numerator for the initial terms, such as $-12-11x-10x^2 -\cdots - x^{11}+x^{13}+2x^{14}+\cdots+12x^{24}$ so a generating function of $$\dfrac{-12-11x-10x^2 -\cdots - x^{11}+x^{13}+2x^{14}+\cdots+12x^{24}}{1-x^{25}}.$$

You could simplify that numerator, for example to $\frac{-12 +13x-13x^{25}+12x^{26}}{(1-x)^2}$,  giving a generating function of  $$\frac{-12 +13x-13x^{25}+12x^{26}}{(1-x)^2(1-x^{25})}.$$

Another approach giving the same answer is to say

- $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ is the generating function for $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots$
- $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is the generating function for $1,1,1,1,1,\ldots$
- so $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{12}{1-x}$ is the generating function for $-12,-11,-10,\ldots$
- but we want the pattern to repeat every $25$ terms so need to divide this by ${1-x^{25}}$ to give $\frac{\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{12}{1-x}}{1-x^{25}}$ and then tidy up

---

You can avoid generating functions.  Since your pattern repeats every $25$ terms, you can consider $n\pmod {25}$ as the remainder on division by $25$.  On its own that will give you a repeating pattern of $0,1,2,\ldots,24$ so you need to subtract $12$ to give you a repeating pattern of $-12,-11,-10,\ldots,12$, or in Excel something like

```
=MOD(A1,25)-12
```